# Is there a way to run Dart's Future synchronously?

Tags: dart

How can I get Future's result immediately? For example:

```dart
void main() {
  Process.run('some_shell_command', []).then((ProcessResult result) {
    print(result.stdout); // I have the output here...
  });
  // ... but want it here.
}
```

Comment: I don't see an easy way of doing that. What's the problem with using the callback? Are you just trying to reduce callback nesting?

Comment: Just want to know whether it's possible.

Answer (score 7):

[the support of `await`](http://dartbug.com/104) is in experimental state and can be used like:

```dart
void main() async {
  ProcessResult result = await Process.run('some_shell_command', []);
  print(result.stdout); // I have the output here...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, it's simply not possible.

There are some cases where a function returns `new Future.immediate(value)` and conceivably you could get the value, but:

1. This isn't one of those cases. Processes are run completely asynchronously by the VM.
2. The ability to access a Future's value directly has been removed in the libv2 update.

The way to handle this is to have the function containing `Process.run()` return a Future, and do all your logic in the callback, which you seem to know, so I'm assuming that your code here is just an example and you're not really doing this in `main()`. In that case, unfortunately, you're basically out of luck - you have to make make your function async if you depend on knowing the future value or that the operation has completed.

Async in a single-threaded environment, like Dart and Javascript, is viral and always propagates up your call stack. Every function that calls this function, and every function that calls them, etc., must be async.

Comment: It seems like the original question was more stylistic in nature, so **await** is definitely the correct answer. That being said, it seems like a Future that executes immediately can be achieved with a custom implementation of Future, e.g. Flutter's [SynchronousFuture](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/1aedbb1835/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/synchronous_future.dart#L17). Note the doc also _highly_ discourages its use as "it is very difficult to debug such bimodal behavior".

Answer (score 0):

No.

The whole point of acync APIs that when the async operation finishes, your code receives the result as a callback.

Another way to write your code, if you're looking to reduce nesting, could be by 
passing in a function to the `then()`

```dart
void main() {
  Process.run('some_shell_command', []).then(doSomethingWithResult);  
}

void doSomethingWithResult(result) {
   print(result.stdout); // I have the output here...
}
```

Comment: There are many cases where you have a function that returns a Future, but you need to use it in contexts where you cannot await for it, like some builder methods in Flutter. In fact, languages like C# do have this capability.